# What could be the reason of bulk load running from Dbeaver during salesforce refresh without fail?

Tags: instance, refresh, dataloader

Can I get some help on the below points please

I am able to run bulk load using Dbeaver during instance refresh not able to understand what could be the reason if the salesforce service brought down then how this is being perform doesn't mean the instance is still active.

I am new to this Salesforce refresh behavior, can I please get some help here.